# How to display mail with html/rich format?

Tags: java, javascript, html, outlook, jakarta-mail

Now I have an app to display a mail with `html/rich` format.
First I retrieve the `html` content via `javamail` `imap` like:

```
if(message.isMimeType("text/html")){


  String content =  message.getContent().toString();


}
```

and then store them into `DB`, but how to display this mail with such a html content?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `JEditorPane` to display HTML content

[Using JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

[Using Swing with HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used a library called [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). Its very simple to retrieve the text-only part for my HTML file. It is very simple.

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

It gives you the text from the HTML file.

I am not sure about the plain text to HTML conversion with Jsoup. But there will be an option for this convertion